# Same width SVG lines render inconsistently

Tags: css, svg, antialiasing

Someone please help me understand what is causing this inconsistency of the line widths. I know there are a lot of questions on this topic, but I couldn't solve my issue with any of them.

I made an SVG border to use with CSS `border-image`.

Here is my CSS:

```
border: 70px solid transparent;
border-image: url("src/assets/images/pixel-border.svg") round;
border-image-slice: 5;
```

Here is my image:

[image]

And this is how it renders on the page:

[image]

**You can clearly see that left & top borders are thicker than right & bottom ones when SVG is used with** `border-image`.

[Here is the reproducible example](https://codepen.io/demiavaliani/pen/LYRdeax)

Interestingly, the SVG is rendered perfectly when used with `background-image`.

[Here is the codepen for that:](https://codepen.io/demiavaliani/pen/MWjVQVe)

Comment: presumably you've drawn part of the line beyond the canvas bounds.

Comment: @Robert I think that's not the case. I made sure when drawing in inkscape that every pixel is perfect. I think it's has something to do with how chrome renders the SVG.

Comment: Add the SVG markup and show us then. I.e provide a [mcve], something we can run ourselves.

Comment: What browser are you using, on which OS?  The border widths seem equal for me in Chrome and FF on Win10.

Comment: Chrome Beta latest version, Win10. The width differences are visible in the codepen example too. In Edge the line edges are blurred out, but I don't care about Edge right now.

Comment: The border widths are unequal as you describe at least on my Windows10 Edge. I've looked at your svg and it seems to be OK in terms of the borders being equal width.

Comment: Okay, so I was able to temporarily fix the issue by adding just 1px of extra white space around the sides in canvas itself (i'm using inkscape). Looks like somehow border-image is cutting the edges off a bit, or maybe I'm using it wrong. But anyways, this fixed the problem but not in it's core, so I won't post this as an answer just yet, maybe someone will post a real solution.